# New use for a post notice?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/353288/58761) has an interesting use of a post notice which is usually used for answers which don't meet SE standards.

It seems not to pertain to the OP's question, which appears to have enough context, but more as a warning to users posting an answer. Seems appropriate enough, but then it would make more sense to post this notice with every new question.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, it could become standard usage, not very effective though, the question has received  3 one-line answers so far, despite the notice.

Comment: I'm sure this has come up before in Meta, although I can't find it. Using that post notice on *questions* is not really new. However (thanks to this question) I've now added it to a couple of answers and protected the question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I never saw it used this way before, but I kind of like it, especially for a Hot Network Question. Should it be used more often?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is not unique to this site. It was [originally implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107142/323179) for Skeptics, as a way to indicate an answer requires citation.

Applying it to a question helps the message be visible for those looking to answer. Applying it to an answer is more of a message to the poster (and anyone looking to edit).

---

[Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasnotice%3Ayes+locked%3Ano) you can find ALL the posts with notices (excluding the lock notices) on ELU. There's not very many (a number of which are on that linked question and its answers). I think that it might be good to use the banner a bit more often, especially with [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) that get tons of one-line answers. On the other hand, I think that adding it to *every* question will ruin its effectiveness as we get desensitized.

Comment: Thank you for the link and explanation. I had never seen it used on questions; I must not be reading many questions anymore. I think your idea of limiting it to SWRs is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if this is aimed at comments posted as answers (as is mine in the question linked to) as well as brief answers posted without supporting evidence.

It has been my practice to do this if I have what amounts to a useful suggestion that I cannot back up (for whatever reason). At least the OP has some sort of answer and anyone else is welcome to take it up and turn it into a fully-formed answer if they are willing and able.

Perhaps 'comments posted as answers' are tolerated more readily in ELL, but if the site owners/moderators want to discourage such actions in EL&U or across the board, then for most of the time I would simply not bother and let questions go unanswered.

Comment: Deleted. Answers my question.